# Isometries of the elliptical/projective space

Tags: geometry, projective-space, isometry

### Preliminaries

Let $\mathbb E ^ n$ denote the elliptical space of order $n$:
$$ \mathbb E ^ n = \mathbb S ^ n / \sim$$
where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation identifying $x$ and $-x$. This can also be thought of as the real projective space of order n $\mathbb{RP}^n$ by identifying lines through the origin with their intersection with $\mathbb S ^n$. Equip $\mathbb E^n$ with the following metric $\varepsilon$:
$$ \varepsilon([x], [y]) = \arccos(\lvert \langle x, y \rangle \rvert) .$$
I want to show that the isometries of this space are all induced by isometries of the n-sphere $\mathbb S ^ n$ (e.g. by the orthogonal group $O(n+1)$).
For example, let $U \in O(n+1)$ be an orthogonal matrix. Then $U$ induces an isometry $f_U$ of $\mathbb E ^ n$ like this:
$$ f_U([x]) = [Ux].$$
Clearly this is an isometry of $\mathbb E ^n$, as orthogonal matrices preserve the inner product.

### What have I done

Let $f$ be an isometry of $\mathbb E ^n$ and denote by $e_i$ the i-th unit vector. Choose $w_i \in f([e_i])$. Clearly $\{w_1, \dots, w_{n+1} \}$ is an orthonormal base of $\mathbb R ^ {n+1}$. Here is where I am stuck. Obviously it matters which $w_i$ we choose, as for each $i$ we have two choices. We want to choose the $w_i$ such that for the matrix $W=\left( w_1, \dots , w_{n+1}\right)$ we have $f=f_W$. But I can't really make out a criteria on how to choose the $w_i$.

After the $w_i$ are choosen correctly we also have to show that $f([x]) = [Wx]$ for all $x\in \mathbb S ^ n$. This is easy to show for the unit vectors, but I have no idea how to show it in general, as there is no notion of linearity for $f$. One can probably use the isometric property of $f$ for $x = \sum x_i e_i$ and $y = \sum y_i w_i \in f([x])$
$$\varepsilon (f([x]), f([e_i])) = \varepsilon([x], [e_i])$$
canceling the $\arccos$ gives us
$$\lvert y_i \rvert  = \lvert \langle y, w_i \rangle \rvert = \lvert \langle x, e_i \rangle \rvert = \lvert x_i \rvert.$$

Comment: Observation: $W$ and $-W$ are the same operation on $\mathbb E$, so there can be no unique way to choose the $w_i$. Just an idea: you could pick $(n+1)^{-1/2}\sum e_i$, the centroid of the unit vectors, and map that. You get two images for that, pick one, then choose all the $w_i$ so they minimize Euclidean distance to that.